# raise converted from None pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: mismatched input 'State' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 46)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting this error while running the query.

ERROR:

[image]

I have read a csv file and using spark sql i have tried the groupby function ,but i am getting  the following error.
This is the data in tempview
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVQec.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct, there is a **space between the group and by** in the query

Such that:

```
spark.sql("select RecordNumber from Temp1 group by State").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I'm getting another error its showing

Comment: And what is the new error? My answer is correct, right?

Comment: The new error is  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: expression 'temp1.RecordNumber' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
Aggregate [State#102], [RecordNumber#98]
+- SubqueryAlias temp1
   +- View (`Temp1`, [RecordNumber#98,Country#99,City#100,Zipcode#101,State#102])
      +- Relation [RecordNumber#98,Country#99,City#100,Zipcode#101,State#102] csv